# Assert List of Maps in Java using Junit Assert

Tags: java, junit, assertion

I am trying to assert 2 List<Map<String, Object>> using the following codes:

```
Assert.assertTrue(first.size() == second.size() &&  first.containsAll(second) && second.containsAll(first));
```

but I am getting assertion error.

I tried converting the 2 Lists to String and assert them using this code:

```
Assert.assertEquals(first.toString, second.toString);
```

It actually worked but I also want to assert them as List of maps in case the arrangements are changed. Is there any other way where I could assert them as List of Map. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because map is not ordered collection. To check the equality you have to traverse through both the list one by one and then check map element exist in other map. If all match then only it will return true else false.

```
List<Map<String,Object> l1,l2 = new ArrayList<>();
 int count=0;
 if(l1.size() == l2.size())
  {
    for(Map m : l1)
     {
       for(Map m1 : l2)
        {
          if(m.equals(m1))
          count++;
          break;
        }
    }   
}  

 if(count == l1.size())
  {
    system.out.println("Equal Map")
  }
```

Comment: how can i do that?